# XY coordinates of rotated HTML elements corners

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, math

Trying to get HTML element's XY coordinates, So I can calculate physical distance in pixels from the corners of a rotated element relative to another element.

In the snippet I try to calculate the distance of the left-top corner of the inner div, to the center of the outer div. But I only have the values **Left** and **Top** of a non rotated div. I need the values to reflect the XY point of the rotated div. Is there any way to get that point, relative to the viewport or to another element?

I've tried `getBoundingClientRect()` but it gives bigger rect and wrong coordinates, because it's actually a vertical box containing the complete rotated div.

So, Is there any way to get those coordinates please?

```js
document.getElementById('outRotated').innerHTML = clacDistancCornerCenter() + "  Rotated distance of corner to center: "


function clacDistancCornerCenter() {
  var outer = document.getElementById('outer');
  var inner = document.getElementById('inner');

  var centerX = outer.offsetWidth / 2;
  var centerY = outer.offsetHeight / 2;


  var innersCornerX = outer.offsetLeft;
  var innersCornerY = outer.offsetTop;

  //distance formula -> d = sqrt( pow( x2 - x1)  + pow( y2 - y1) )

  var distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(centerX - innersCornerX, 2) + Math.pow(centerY - innersCornerY, 2));

  return distance;
}

function calcDistHorizontal() {
  $('div').css('transform', 'rotate(0deg)');
  document.getElementById('outHorizontal').innerHTML = clacDistancCornerCenter()+ "  This Should be differnt when horizontal: ";
}
```

```css
div {
  top: 15%;
  left: 20%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  transform: rotate(25deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="outRotated"> </p>
<p id="outHorizontal"> </p>

<button onclick="calcDistHorizontal()">Distance Horizontal</button>

<div id="outer">
  <div id="mid">
    <div id="inner">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure if there is a direct way. But if you know the non-rotated coordinates, the rotation angle and the rotation origin, you could calculate it manually with some math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a simple solution, with no extra math... I create a new element of 0px width to represent a point. I place it in the corner which I want to measure to, then ask for the viewport coordinates with getBoundingClientRect(), which returns a rectangle object with the top, bottom, left and right all relative to the screens viewport. And since the point element has 0 width/height thus top equals to bottom and left equals to right.

```js
clacDistancCornerCenter();


function clacDistancCornerCenter() {
  var center = document.getElementById('center').getBoundingClientRect();
  var corner = document.getElementById('corner').getBoundingClientRect();

  //alert("left =" + center.left + "top =" + center.top + "right =" + center.right + "bottom =" + center.bottom);

  var centerX = center.left;
  var centerY = center.top;


  var innersCornerX = corner.left;
  var innersCornerY = corner.top;

  //distance formula -> d = sqrt( pow( x2 - x1)  + pow( y2 - y1) )

  var distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(centerX - innersCornerX, 2) + Math.pow(centerY - innersCornerY, 2));

  document.getElementById('outRotated').innerHTML = "Distance center to corner: "+ distance;
}

function horizontal() {

  $('div').css('transform', 'rotate(0deg)');

}


function relocate(top, left) {
  var point = document.getElementById('corner');
  if (top) {
    point.style.bottom = 'auto';
    point.style.top = 0;
  } else {
    point.style.top = 'auto';
    point.style.bottom = 0;

  }

  if (left) {
    point.style.right = 'auto';
    point.style.left = 0;
  } else {
    point.style.left = 'auto';
    point.style.right = 0;
  }
  clacDistancCornerCenter();
}
```

```css
div {
  top: 15%;
  left: 20%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  transform: rotate(25deg);
}
.point {
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  background-color: blue;
  //border:3px solid blue;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}
#center {
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="outRotated"></p>
<p id="outRotated"> Set points width and height to 0 to get the actual correct distance. For now the points are large for easy understanding</p>

<br/>
<button onclick="relocate(true,true)">Top Left</button>-------
<button onclick="relocate(true,false)">Top Right</button>
<br/>
<button onclick="relocate(false,true)">Bottom Left</button>
<button onclick="relocate(false,false)">Bottom Right</button>
<br/>
<button onclick="horizontal()">Horizontal</button>

<div id="outer">
  <span id="center" class="point" onclick="outputXY()"></span>
  <div id="mid">
    <div id="inner">
      <span id="corner" class="point" onclick="outputXY()"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note: this only works if transformed element has position style set explicitly to relative or absolute.

Answer (score 1):

To do this with any css 2d transform you can use getComputedStyle and use the transform matrix to get the transformed coordinates.

```
function calcElemTransformedPoint(elem, point)
{
    var style = getComputedStyle(elem);
    var transformOrigin = style.transformOrigin.split(' ').map(function(e)
    {
        // Remove 'px' and cast to number
        return +e.slice(0,-2);
    });
    var p = [point[0] - transformOrigin[0], point[1] - transformOrigin[1]];
    var transform = style.transform;
    // Matrix
    var m = [];
    if(transform.slice(0,7) === 'matrix(')
        m = transform.slice(7,-1).split(',').map(function(e){ return +e; });
    else
    {
        // 'matrix3d('
        var tmp = transform.slice(9,-1).split(',');
        m = [
            +tmp[0],
            +tmp[1],
            +tmp[4],
            +tmp[5],
            +tmp[12],
            +tmp[13]
        ];
    }
    // Matrix multiplication
    return [
        p[0] * m[0] + p[1] * m[2] + m[4] + transformOrigin[0],
        p[0] * m[1] + p[1] * m[3] + m[5] + transformOrigin[1]
    ];
}
```

#### [Usage example](https://jsfiddle.net/fdsnvs3q/)

Answer (score 0):

Math!

If you had a point class called Vector, with an x and a y property, you could use a method like this to get the final XY coords:

```
vA.getVectorRotated = function(vB, angle){
   angle = angle*Math.PI/180;
   return new Vector( (Math.cos(angle) * (this.x - vB.x)
                     - Math.sin(angle) * (this.y - vB.y) + vB.x),
                      (Math.sin(angle) * (this.x - vB.x) 
                     + Math.cos(angle) * (this.y - vB.y) + vB.y) );
};
```

Comment: This looks interesting but it needs vA and vB better explained to be usable by those who don't understand this level of math.